# How can i send data from ToolPart1 class to WebPart1 class

Tags: sharepoint

I cannot send a array data from ToolPart to WebPart although string data is oke. I debug and know that the statement code webpart.ListColumns[i] = lstBoxSend.Items[i].Value is right and have data but i dont know why property ListColumns in WebPart is null

```
public class ToolPart1 : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ToolPart
         {
              public override void ApplyChanges()
                 {
                   base.ApplyChanges();
                   var webpart = (WebPart1)this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart;
                   webpart.SiteUrl = txtURL.Text;
                   webpart.ListName = ddlList.SelectedValue;

                   if (webpart.ListColumns == null)
                     {
                       webpart.ListColumns = new string[lstBoxSend.Items.Count];
                     }
                   for (int i = 0; i < lstBoxSend.Items.Count; i++)
                     {
                       webpart.ListColumns[i] = lstBoxSend.Items[i].Value;
                     }
                  }
          }
    public class WebPart1 : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart
    {

        public string SiteUrl { get; set; }
        public string ListName { get; set; }
        public string[] ListColumns { get; set; }

   }
```

I want receive array data in WebPart From ToolPart

Answer (score 0):

Override ApplyChanges to send data to webpart, check [this demo](http://sharepointrenancr.blogspot.com/2013/04/working-with-toolpart-and-webpart.html)

```
public override void ApplyChanges()
    {
        int i = 0;
        WebPartCustom1 wpCustom = (WebPartCustom1)this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart;
        int.TryParse(_itensToolPart.Text, out i);
        wpCustom.MyInt = i;
        wpCustom.MyString = _titleToolPart.Text;
        wpCustom.MyGuid = _ddlToolPart.SelectedItem.Value;      
    }
```

Comment: I want to receive a array string[] ListColumns in WebPart1 that was sent by ToolPart1.